# Any open source alternative to MyHDL?

Tags: vhdl, hdl, vlsi

Is there any open source alternative to [MyHDL](http://electronicsforu.com/buyers-guides/software-buyers-guide/myhdl-python-based-hardware-description-language)? I have started learning but finding it very difficult.

Comment: You might be better off learning the underlying VHDL first, then you can see what MyHDL is doing.

Answer (score 1):

If you're planning to actually use it (e.g. to program an FPGA), [GEZEL](http://rijndael.ece.vt.edu/gezel2/) might be a good choice.

But if you're just starting out and only looking to learn, have a look at the first few chapters/projects of [nand2tetris](http://www.nand2tetris.org). They have a custom HDL which is easy to understand and introduced step by step.